# WooCommerce product category permalinks

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

Is there any way to set WooCommerce product category without `category-base` word(s)? Current category url, [www.example.com/product-category/t-shirt](http://www.example.com/product-category/t-shirt). But, I need to set category url like this one, [www.example.com/t-shirt](http://www.example.com/t-shirt). Please let me know, what is the procedure?

**N.B:** I have tried dot(.) as `category-base` but, it url not working.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue.